# Unable to redraw form border on paint event

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2013

I am looking to make a custom border for my main form after a splash screen (i.e. the first form that loads) in my program's GUI. As suggested by the GoogleGods, I set the FormBorderStyle to "None". And then on the paint command of the class, I added this code:

```
Private Sub MainWindow_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, Me.Bounds)
  '  ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, ClientRectangle, Color.Black,    ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)
 End Sub
```

I also tried it with the commented out portion instead (starting with ControlPaint.draw....) and that didn't work either. The main issue being that the form shows no line drawn around the form in any manner.

What's stopping my code from showing a new border? Is there a better way to redraw it (and possibly have it have the same features as the default border, i.e. re sizing and moving the form when clicked)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `DrawRect` is mainly for drawing inside the form client area, but it probably is drawing a rectangle, just not where you think.  Change to `Pens.Red` or something more noticeable to see.

To draw a custom border this should work:

```
ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle, Color.Red, 
            ButtonBorderStyle.Inset)
```

When debugging this kind of thing, it helps to use a vivid color like RED, a 1 pixel line in black can be hard to notice.  For one that is custom and sizeable, [see this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24005/Resizable-Moveable-Customizable-Borderless-Form).

Comment: I tried it with the red code you added, again no line shows up. The controls are white so it's an easy contrast to see. I've had success on the non main windows with the same code. Is there a possibility of that being the source of the problem?

Comment: is there something else special about the mainform?  That code came from a standard form's paint event and works fine.  DrawRect with bounds would have drawn in the wrong location.

Comment: It has a datagrid view, a menu strip, and a context menu strip. I'm thinking maybe the line is not "brought to front" or these aren't docked correctly? That's what it seems at this point, since that's the main difference from the other forms.

Comment: the menu and anything docked will cover at least portions of the line being drawn.  this doesnt draw a "real" border *around* the form client, but just *inside* it where docked controls can cover it.  In the linked article you'll see there is a bit more involved to making a proper border.

Comment: Windows already draws a border on forms for you. Better yet, it's customizable by the user. Do strongly consider using that one, @sparky.